# Error ELECTRON: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'require')

Tags: nodejs, electron

estoy realizando una aplicación con Electron y he tenido problemas con el require/remote. Con varios cambios he pasado del error de que no exista el require a este pero no se como solucionarlo,adjunto el código de mi App.js. Gracias de antemano.

```js
const productForm = document.getElementById('productForm');

const { remote } = require('electron');
const main = remote.require('./main');

const productName = document.getElementById('name');
const productPrice = document.getElementById('price');
const productDescription = document.getElementById('description');

productForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const electronVersion = process.versions.electron;
    console.log(`Estás utilizando Electron v${electronVersion}`);

    const newProduct = {
        name: productName.value,
        price: productPrice.value,
        description: productDescription.value
    };

    main.createProduct(newProduct);
});
```